# Cant change colors of c3 in chart donut angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am getting really desperate here, I need to change all my values dynamically, and for  that I have:

html

```
<c3chart bindto-id="dynamicpie" id="#dynamicpie" chart-data="piePointsAssets"chart-columns="pieColumnsAssets">
<chart-tooltip show-tooltip="false" />
<chart-size chart-width="225" />
<chart-legend show-legend="false" />
</c3chart>
```

javascript

```
var chart = document.getElementById('#dynamicpie');
chart.colors = {                 [$scope.integratedPosition[0].lstEntityIntegratedPosition[j].accountproducttypegroup.GroupName]: [$scope.colors[j]] };
```

my array of colors is never applied. Why? How to properly do this?

Comment: why dont you use driectives?

Comment: I am using a directive as you can see in my answer, I use  " <c3chart  ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem , also I am sorry that the html is not showing in the question, seems to be a mistake on my part.

solution:

```
 <c3chart bindto-id="dynamicpie" id="#dynamicpie" chart-data="piePointsAssets" chart-columns="pieColumnsAssets">
                    <chart-tooltip show-tooltip="false" />
                    <chart-size chart-width="225" />
                    <chart-legend show-legend="false" />
                    <chart-colors color-pattern="{{colorStringParam}}" />
                </c3chart>
```

js:

```
     $scope.colorStringParam = "";

...
     $scope.colorStringParamRes += $scope.colors[k] + ",";
```